# how to insert doctype for html5 in icefaces1.8

Tags: html, doctype, icefaces

I've a legacy icefaces1.8 application. There is a template.xhtml used by other .xhtml file. The template.xhtml file that contains

```
<ice:outputDeclaration 
doctypeRoot="HTML" 
doctypePublic="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
doctypeSystem="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" />
```

I want `<!DOCTYPE html>` but am finding it difficult to do so. Upgrading to a newer version of icefaces is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution

```
<ice:outputDeclaration 
doctypeRoot="HTML" 
doctypePublic="" 
doctypeSystem="" />
```

generates `<!doctype html>`